# How on click button put animation for busy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How on click button put animation for busy, show popup with that circle and to block all other ( be dark) while not finish job ( 5 sec ) ? I am new and I don't have any idea how to solve this.

Comment: What is this "job"? An Ajax call?

Comment: @Felix Kling just wait 5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

your question is not so clear .
i think you want to do this.

[jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

Answer (score 0):

If you create an element which overlays the page, items under it won't be clickable. To create the overlay, you could just create a new element and remove it using a timeout:

```
var overlay = $('<div />').css('opacity',0.5).addClass('overlay').appendTo('body');

$(overlay).append($('<div />').text('Loading '))
 window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(overlay).remove();
},5000);
```

as for the CSS of the overlay, you could use something like this:

```
.overlay{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background:#000;
  text-align:center;  
}

.overlay div{
    margin-top:100px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:22px;
}
```

example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/BKWjY/